# How to store JSON data with images and or videos offline?

Tags: iphone, ios, offlineapps, offline-mode

I have an app which displays text data with images and or videos which is displayed in a `UITableView`. I have a requirement now that the data must be available offline. I am thinking of pruge and store data every time I have a connection i.e new data is being downloaded. How can this be achieved - storing the data in a mysql table or any other solution. Please note that I am using AFNetworking to stream the images in uiimageview. The images and videos should be stored as blob is the local mysql database? Please note that my project is not using coredata.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way would probably be to download and store the media files in the `caches` directory.

Then, when you need to access a file, you can check to see if it exists, and if so, use it, and if not, handle that condition in whatever manner you need.

```
NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSString *cachePath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSCachesDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
if(![fileManager fileExistsAtPath:[cachePath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"myfile.zip"]]) {
    //create it, copy it from app bundle, download it etc.
}
//start using it
```

The caches directory is not backed up with the rest of your app, so if you have large files you will not impact the user's backup storage sizes this way.

If you absolutely *must* have the files in the backup, use the `Documents` directory instead of the `caches` directory.

You said you were using `AFNetworking`, which can stream a download to a file just fine, and even has support for turning the task into a background operation so that it can finish after the app has been closed.

Comment: Hello thanks for your response. U mean i should store the images & JSON data in the caches directory?

Comment: That's right Veereef. Store the images and json data in your caches directory, and then before you access them check to see if they are there. If not, download them.

Comment: Thanks will do as suggested.